# How to properly set the HTML contents using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this javascript code where it goes for each movies in `jsonp` dataType. For each movies I have to display its thumbnail image and its title together with the star rating. To display the star symbols below for each movies I have this code:

```
var include = '<div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="2.5" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true"></div>';
$(".prediction").html(include); //DISPLAYS THE PREDICTION RATING
```

It simply sets the html content of the class `prediction` to this -> `<div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="2.5" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true"></div>`
I tried to use this on directly on my html code and it is fully working I can see the stars. Here it is:[image]
But I tried this on javascript and it is not displaying. I just want to have ratings below for each and every movies.

This is my javascript code:

```
var html = '';
var count = 0;

$.each(data.movies, function(index, movie) {    
    html += '<div  class="item col-xs-6 col-md-3">';
    html += '<div class="thumbnail" style="min-height:320px;max-height:320px;">';
        //add link here 
    html += '<a href="viewMovieDetails.php?id=' + movie.id + '">'
    html += '<img src="' + movie.posters.detailed + '" style="width:175px; height: 230px;" class="img-responsive" alt="" ></a>';
    html += '<div class="caption">';
    html += '<h5>' + movie.title + '</h5>';

    html += '<div class="prediction"></div>';
    html += '</div></div></div>';


    //set a delay (1second) for a call on rotten tomatoes api and
    //store data on db
    if(count > 5){
        setTimeout(function() { storeDataOnDB(movie.id);; }, 1000);
        count = 0;
    }
    else{
        count++;
    }
});

// Append movies
$('#movie_recommend').html(html);   

var include = '<div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="2.5" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true"></div>';
$(".prediction").html(include); //DISPLAYS THE PREDICTION RATING
```

What do you think is wrong? Am I missing something? or is there other way to do it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried to open console? Are there any errors?

Comment: @nikis, there are no any error just a warning. `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. `. I'm pretty sure that it's not the cause.

Comment: Have you placed `jquery.rateit.min.js` before </body> tag?

Comment: @nikis, Yes...I've already tested it directly in HTML and it is working.

Comment: Strange. I've made something like you have and it's working fine http://jsfiddle.net/TLtD9/1/

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: @nikis, This is my HTML that gets the value of the javascript -> `<div id="movie_recommend" class="row list-group"></div><!--End Movie recommend-->`. Do you want me to post the whole HTML code?

Comment: @nikis, by the way this is the site where I got the rating plugin : http://rateit.codeplex.com/

Comment: now, when the problem is resolved, it's better to remove comment with pastebin links, since API key can be found there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should notify `RateIt` plugin, that new data is available, just add this:

```
$(".rateit").rateit();
```

after `$(".prediction").html(include);`